# Build Pytorch from source

Tags: python, macos, pytorch

I'm trying to install Pytorch from source on my MacOS (version 10.14.3) to use GPU. I have follow the documentation from this [link](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#mac-verification). When I launch in my terminal the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++ python setup.py install` I'm getting the following error in my terminal:

```
[ 69%] Built target caffe2_observers make: *** [all] Error 2 Traceback (most recent
call last): File "setup.py", line 710, in <module>
build_deps() 
File "setup.py", line 282, in build_deps 
build_dir='build')
File "/Users/Desktop/pytorch/tools/build_pytorch_libs.py", line 259, in build_caffe2
check_call(['make', '-j', str(max_jobs), 'install'], cwd=build_dir, env=my_env)
File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-j', '4', 'install']'
returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

I tried to upgrade pip and reinstall anaconda and cuda without success.

Here you can find the error just belong :

```
[ 69%] Building CXX object modules/observers/CMakeFiles/caffe2_observers.dir/net_observer_reporter_print.cc.o
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:115:
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/crt/common_functions.h:77:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
CMake Error at caffe2_gpu_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o.Release.cmake:219 (message):
    Error generating
/Users/Desktop/pytorch/build/caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/__/aten/src/THC/./caffe2_gpu_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o

make[2]: *** [caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/__/aten/src/THC/caffe2_gpu_generated_THCReduceApplyUtils.cu.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Scanning dependencies of target torch_shm_manager
1 error generated.
```

Comment: What happens if you `cd` into the source directory (i.e., wherever the `Makefile` is) and run `make -j 4 install` ?

Comment: I have the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.setup_helpers'; '__main__' is not a package` before running `make -j 4 install`

Comment: There should be more details about the actual issue printed, before the message you provided. Can you find this info?

Comment: I didn't see it. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encountering this problem because Nvidia is incompatible with OSX Mojave 10.14+

Answer (score 2):

> **<sub>/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15:fatal error: 'string.h' file not found</sub>**

It appears you are missing the `C++` header `string.h`; my suggestion would be to try to install/reinstall the Xcode Command-Line tools if you haven't already:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

If the command-line tools are already installed then perhaps uninstall (by removing the directory):

```
$ rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Once done removing try the first command again, then check to see if `string.h` is installed:

```
$ find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr -type f -name string.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h
```

Comment: I install again Xcode and I found string.h in the good folder but the installation of PyTorch gives me the same error I described.

Comment: @Jonor: Be sure to clean the cmake build cache.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how can I do it. Can you explain or I will have a look on the web

Comment: @Jonor: cd into pytorch directory and `rm -rf build`. When you say you have the same error, it’s “file not found”, string.h?

Comment: Exactly, I have done the `rm -rf build` and I have launched again the installation which have begun from 0% (while it goes directly to 69% before)

Comment: @Jonor: Okay that’s what you want; If that doesn’t resolve it then there’s a couple other suggestions I might have, although hopefully this will do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189873/discussion-between-jonor-and-lll).

Comment: For reference, `rm -rf build` helped with a different, but related problem when installing pytorch from source in macOS

Comment: Getting the exact same problem now @Jonor, did you find a solution?