# GPU driver and CUDA is not enabled and accessible by PyTorch on MacOS

Tags: macos, installation, pytorch

GPU driver and CUDA is not enabled and accessible by PyTorch.
`torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `false`

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.6
I have installed Cuda 10.0 version of pytorch. 
I tried verfication on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and constructing a randomly initialized tensor works just fine.

But when I tried

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_availalbe()
```

it returns false.

Therefore, I followed instructions on Pytorch and installed Anaconda and Cuda.

Then tried this:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++ python setup.py install`

In terminal, I got

```
fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
```

I searched on stackoverflow and came up with this. [Build Pytorch from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107466/build-pytorch-from-source) . So I tried:

```
$ find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr -type f -name string.h
```

which returned `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h`

Doesn't this mean I already have `string.h`?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: MacOS doesn't still have good NVIDIA (GPU) support switch to Linux as friendly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing from a conda env? According to the github this should work:
 - Create a conda env
 - `conda install numpy ninja pyyaml mkl mkl-include setuptools cmake cffi typing`  (that installs some requirements)
 Then this (which I assume you've already done):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch
# if you are updating an existing checkout
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And finally set up the conda variable and install:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX:-"$(dirname $(which conda))/../"}
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++ python setup.py install
```

There are issues on the git reporting that behavior [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/25669) which suggest to add something like:
`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++ NO_CUDA=1 python setup.py install`

Check that`NO_CUDA`, this issue as also been mentioned [HERE](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/fatal-error-during-mac-source-build/38436/3) in the forums and it seems to be that it could be an issue caused by the OS and driver versions. If that should be the case I recommend to use [Nvidia Docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) (hopefully it has mac support) with a pytorch container from https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/landing
It that should also fail, your best bet is to install without CUDA support.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried what you wrote above for me.
`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 CC=clang CXX=clang++ NO_CUDA=1 python setup.py install` this still returns `string.h file not found` error.